# Java (Android) WebSocket Client Libraries

Tags: java, android, http, websocket

There are some libraries to implement WebSocket usage in an unobtrusive fashion. Apparently, there are many libraries out, but what I really looking is a modern and small library which I can use on Android or Java in generall to implement my WebSocket usage from the client side.

So far I have found:

- [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)
- [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/)
- [JAX-RS 2.0](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/)

I am missing a bit the differences of the differnet libraries. JAX-RS 2.0 for instance seems to be a great foundation for a lot of implementations, but I also went with Square's Retrofit for my RESTful Client because it was just leaner and easy to integrate.

Comment: [Project Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) is your friend.

Comment: **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** is a new WebSocket client library written in Java. It requires just Java SE 1.5, so it can run on Android. The size of `nv-websocket-client-1.3.jar` (released on 2015-05-06) is 62,854 bytes and it does not require any external dependencies. See "[WebSocket client library (Java SE 1.5+, Android)](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html)" for details.

Answer (score 4):

I just work on one of my first web socket app in android. So I do lot of R&D before I starting and at last I found these two libs are very simple and useful for my requirement.

1 ) AndroidAsync (For clients )

2 ) Java-WebSocket (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket ) for Server

Both are very simple and easy to use.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that server library. It isn't being maintained and it has lots of open issues.

Comment: Hi @khurram i assume you are talking about this library https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync . i couldn't find a proper example on simple connect send and receive data from server. Can you help me with any

Comment: Yes Deepak you are right, I have used same library in my project and its simple to use, please let me know how can I help you if you are still looking for it.